# Angular JS Testing with Karma Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a **sample route** like this :

```
  angular
        .module('appRouter',['ui.router'])
        .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
            $stateProvider
                .....
                .....
                .state('settings.account',{
                    url:'/account',
                    templateUrl:'templates/account.html',
                    controller:function(resolveData){
                        console.log(resolveData);
                    },
                    resolve:{
                        resolveData : function($http){
                            var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
                            return $http.get(root+'/posts/1').then(function(response){

                                return response.data;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

            .....
```

**It is just a test URL where I can get sample JSON data online**

`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`

**I wanted to test the state.**

```
  beforeEach(function(){
        module('appRouter');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_,_$injector_,_$state_,_$httpBackend_,$templateCache){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $state = _$state_;
        $injector = _$injector_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $templateCache.put('templates/account.html','');
    }));

   it('should resolve "resolveData"',function(){
        const state = $state.get('settings.account');
        const resolveFn = state.resolve.resolveData;

                $httpBackend.whenGET('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').respond(function(){
        return [
            200,{
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "title": "...",
                "body": "..."
        }]
    });

    $httpBackend.expectGET('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');

    $injector.invoke(resolveFn);

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect($injector.annotate(resolveFn)).toEqual(['$http']);

    console.log(angular.mock.dump($scope));

    expect($scope.resolveData).toEqual({
         "userId": 1,
         "id": 1,
         "title": "...",
         "body": "..."
     });
```

But this fails. Saying

```
1) should resolve "resolveData"
     UI Routerer Config For Account
     Expected undefined to equal Object({ userId: 1, id: 1, title: '...', body: '...' }).
    at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:114:36)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

`console.log(angular.mock.dump($scope));` gives the following

[image]

Please help.

Comment: I think there was value in the original question you asked (before the edit), with the original error. This new error message should be a new question. They are both two separate problems, that should be handled individually.

Comment: i dont understand exactly what are you trying to test here. I mean: tests should examine if your code is doing some logic you expect it to do. But instead (as far as i can see) your test examines if you can get some json from some request. Thats not the purpose of tests. May be it is good purpose of server side tests. Instead i suggest you to call some service inside the "resolve" (just replace the $http call by injecting some service and call one of its methods), now you can test ifs service is called in response of "state.go", and if service called with corrrect params. (Thats my opinion)

Answer (score 2):

**Original Error:**

```
should resolve "resolveData"
UI Routerer Config For Account
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
  at resolveData (app/appRouter.js:25:41)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:97:9)
```

> What am I doing wrong?

You are calling `resolveFn()` in your unit test. The function was defined as requiring the `$http` service, and that call does not pass the `$http` service (as [fingerpich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128151/fingerpich) mentioned).

To correct this, allow angular to handle the dependency injection by using `$injector.invoke(resolveFn)`.

See this in action with a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/4FiNz4?p=preview). Note the test does fail for a different reason. But, (if I understand the rules correctly) that is a different issue should be answered with a different question (if you need more help).

A side note: When the site (not the unit test) is opened in a browser, I would expect it to work, because angular injects the `$http` dependency into the function assigned to `resolveData`.

Look at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29128751/4962272) that also references the blog mentioned by [fingerpich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128151/fingerpich).

Here is a blog I found helpful when learning about [unit testing AngularJS](http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/angularjs-unit-testing/).

Comment: I tried the same but it did not work out for me. It said `Expected undefined to equal Object({ userId: 1, id: 1, title: ...` when I expect `$scope.resolveData` to match the JSON data. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you still receive the error `should resolve "resolveData"... TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined...`? If not, your original question should be resolved and the error mentioned in the comment would fall under a new question.

Comment: Perhaps a little nudge will help with the new error: add `console.log(angular.mock.dump($scope));` prior to the `expect` statement at the end of the test. After that, checkout how the `.then()` is used with the `$injector.invoke()` call [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080657/testing-ui-router-stateprovider-resolve-values/29128751#29128751) (I included this link in my answer).

Comment: `console.log(angular.mock.dump($scope));` gives the error . See the updates.

Comment: moreover      `$injector.invoke($state.get('settings.account').resolve['resolveData'])
            .then(function(res){console.log(res.data);});` gives me `undefined`. I tried to follow the steps mentioned in the answer you referred to.

Comment: Ok, so `res.data` is `undefined`. Back up a step and just log `res` to see if that is defined, which it should be. I expect the data you are looking for to be held by `res`, because your `resolveData` function has this line `return response.data;`; therefore, `resolveData` should be the contents of the `data` property of the http response.

Answer (score 1):

```
should resolve "resolveData"
UI Routerer Config For Account
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
 at resolveData (app/appRouter.js:25:41)
 at Object.<anonymous> (test/controllers/main-controller-spec.js:97:9)
```

to solve this problem you should pass `$http` to resolveData function.

```
resolveFn($http);
```

but it's better to write tests like [this](http://nikas.praninskas.com/angular/2014/09/27/unit-testing-ui-router-configuration/#resolve)

Comment: Sorry but this says ` ReferenceError: $http is not defined` . Please have a look at it.

Comment: I did that. And it failed saying the error I mentioned. How to overcome?